# where to get Urban Airship

Tags: iphone, newsstand-kit

I want to integrate the newsstand feature in my application.

I had done some searching and i found [this](https://github.com/viggiosoft/NewsstandTutorial)  and  [this](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/)

But in both of this I need Urban Airship for push notification

And i got this link too [here](http://urbanairship.com/)
But i am not able to get airship library.please help me

Comment: Did you go through this part of the documentation? https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/iOS+Getting+Started

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for a Basic Plan and you can get the SDK (it's free for the first 1M messages/mo).

https://go.urbanairship.com/accounts/register/

Answer (score 0):

read this link and useful for me, i think this link is your help

[How to use get push notfication from urban air ship](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3a+iOS%3a+Push)

how to implement in your project , [read this](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Client%3a+iOS%3a+Push)

if you want to libraries, [use this](https://github.com/shacked/SuburbanAirship)

Answer (score 0):

Urban Airship is the organization that provide the services for the Push Notifications.
To get the services you will be required to subscribe to the services which in this case are paid.
You can check out the different plans here: [Pricing for Urban Airship services.](http://urbanairship.com/pricing/)

Also please check for the solutions before posting.

Comment: only free trials are available. You can have a trial for 45 days.